# Prometheus datasource : client_error: client error: 403

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, prometheus, monitoring, grafana

Hi I am trying to add built-in OpenShift(v4.8) prometheus data source to a local grafana server. I have given basic auth with username and password and as of now I have enabled skip tls verify also. Still I'm getting this error

[image: error]

Prometheus URL = `https://prometheus-k8s-openshift-monitoring.apps.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.com`

this is the grafana log

```
logger=tsdb.prometheus t=2022-04-12T17:35:23.47+0530 lvl=eror msg="Instant query failed" query=1+1 err="client_error: client error: 403"
logger=context t=2022-04-12T17:35:23.47+0530 lvl=info msg="Request Completed" method=POST path=/api/ds/query status=400 remote_addr=10.100.95.27 time_ms=36 size=65 referer=https://grafana.xxxx.xxxx.com/datasources/edit/6TjZwT87k
```

Comment: facing same issue. i tried with installing grafana on cluster, and configuring it to use on cluster `https://prometheus-k8s.openshift-monitoring.svc:9091` endpoint. but still getting `client_error: client error: 403`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot authenticate to the OpenShift prometheus instance using basic authentication. You need to authenticate using a bearer token, e.g. one obtained from `oc whoami -t`:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(oc whoami -t)" -k https://prometheus-k8s-openshift-monitoring.apps.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.com/
```

Or from a `ServiceAccount` with appropriate privileges:

```
secret=$(oc -n openshift-monitoring get sa prometheus-k8s -o jsonpath='{.secrets[1].name}')
token=$(oc -n openshift-monitoring get secret $secret -o jsonpath='{.data.token}' | base64 -d)
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" -k https://prometheus-k8s-openshift-monitoring.apps.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.com/
```

Comment: Hi @larsks The token obtained from service account doesn't work and gives malformed input while decoding. the `oc whoami` method works but expires after one day. facing similar issue https://github.com/openshift/oauth-proxy/issues/92#issuecomment-434221090

Comment: even if bearer token obtained from `oc whoami -t` works with curl, the prometheus datasource in grafana does not accept token. it acceps user/pass, ca, certs etc

Comment: It looks as if it is possible to set things up, e.g.: https://community.grafana.com/t/use-bearer-token-to-scrape-prometheus/6794/8

Answer (score 0):

openshift uses an operator for grafana(or you should), operators extend it's api and gives you a few new objects to play with. one of those customResourceDefinitions (CRD) is a GrafanaDatasource. To use openshift's default prometheus as a datasource in grafana, you need a service account token with correct permissions to access prometheus. then use a yaml file like below and replace the token with one from that service account

[openshift UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8K2x.png)

```
apiVersion: grafana.integreatly.org/v1beta1
kind: GrafanaDatasource
metadata:
  name: cluster-prometheus
  namespace: grafana
spec:
  datasource:
    access: proxy
    editable: true
    secureJsonData:
      httpHeaderValue1: Bearer c29tZXRva2VudGhhdGhhc3Blcm1pc3Npb24K
    name: prometheus
    url: 'https://thanos-querier.openshift-monitoring.svc.cluster.local:9091'
    jsonData:
      httpHeaderName1: Authorization
      timeInterval: 5s
      tlsSkipVerify: true
    basicAuth: true
    isDefault: true
    type: prometheus
  instanceSelector:
    matchLabels:
      dashboards: grafana
```